# SQL Server Trigger CAST function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I was able to create an INSERT trigger that took a date of birth from one table and converts perfectly to an equivalent table

```
SELECT @DateOfBirth = CAST(INSERTED.DOBIRTH AS DATETIME)
FROM INSERTED
```

But now, I am writing an UPDATE trigger and I want to update the ORIGINAL table; how can I convert that date of birth BACK INTO a 7-digit integer value?

Comment: You made the first mistake of triggers: `INSERTED` can have many rows. You just picked a single arbitrary row in your code. Anyway. Please indicate what format the 7 digit value should have.  Which piece of the date do you want to exclude. Should we guess?  (you need 8 digits to describe a date)

Comment: 1968010 is one date of birth.

Comment: Is that the zeroth of January?

Comment: Assuming this is SQL Server that won't even cast to datetime, even if you were to do it properly and use `CONVERT`. Please explain what format that piece of data is in? By inspection, it appears to be missing data. If 1968 is the year, how do you describe a two digit month and a digit day in three digits?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 7 digit date format is YYYYDDD, the year and the day (1-365[6]) of the year.
Here is one way to do it:

```
SELECT CAST(YEAR(@DateOfBirth) AS varchar) + 
    RIGHT('000' + 
        CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(YEAR(@DateOfBirth) AS varchar) + '-01-01', @DateOfBirth)+1 AS varchar)
        , 3)
```

I take the year part of the date and concatenate the number of days since the beginning of the year.  I also pad the left side with 0's for days before *100*.

So *2017-01-01* becomes *2017001* and *2017-12-31* becomes *2017365*.

Comment: @JohnEdwardLaw for the entirety of this question you did not explain the date format. For your next question include this vital information

Comment: Well I had intended to add that but given that the answer was given in the form of "The 7 digit date format is YYYYDDD" and I was able to quickly make use of it, I was unable to get in ahead of the person who answered. Next time, I shall endeavor to make sure that that is included up front.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the 7-digit integer is.  You can convert it to an integer using:

```
select convert(int, format(dob, 'yyyyMMdd'))
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
select  year(dob) * 10000 + month(dob) * 100 + day(dob)
```